Physics Properties in Blender 4.3 ( Viscosity)
i was using blender 4.3 while trying to create a Chocolate for my product animation ad but i cant do the chocolate in blender 4.3 because it have been removed is there is any thing i can do to make it happen? and Why blender removed the Viscosity?

This has nothing to do with the Cycles render engine.

The viscosity setting is under the Diffusion panel of the Fluid settings on the fluid domain. See documentation.
